# ¿Cómo reparo un video de OBS que dice Moov Atom Not Found?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding

Recientemente gravé un video con OBS y olvidé terminar la grabación adecuadamente. Además mande a pagar la máquina. El video generado al reproducirlo muestra el mensaje de Error  "Moov Atom Not Found"

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe a la falta de una cabecera que describa el contenido del video.

Para reparlo usé la palicación [untrunc](https://github.com/anthwlock/untrunc)

Que tiene versiones para Windows y linux.

En Windows cuenta con una interfaz gráfica que solicita el video dañado y un video generado con la misma cámara (en este caso OBS). La aplicación reconstruye la cabecera y deja un video con el nombre Fixed.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]